# How can I use while or for loop to count when value exceed the given number?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

this my work
I have a problem with the question is the last passenger should not be counted if their weight added to the total passenger weight exceeds the carrying capacity.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exam2
{   
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int inputmax ;
        int inputweight;
        int thesum = 0;
        int count =0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter maximum of weight: ");
        inputmax = sc.nextInt();
        while(inputmax < 1 )
        {
        System.out.println("Enter positive number of maximum of weight: ");
        inputmax = sc.nextInt();
        }
       while(thesum < inputmax)
       {
           System.out.println("Enter each of weight: ");
           inputweight = sc.nextInt();

           while ( inputweight < 0)
            {
            System.out.println("Enter positive number of weight: ");
            inputweight = sc.nextInt(); 
            }
            thesum += inputweight;
            count++;   
        }
        System.out.println("Number of people could carry is: " + count);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is currently wrong with it?

Comment: You have to check if the result will exceed the capacity before adding it: `if (thesum + inputweight >= inputmax) { break; } else { thesum += inputweight; count++; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(thesum < inputmax) {
    System.out.println("Enter each of weight: ");
    inputweight = sc.nextInt();

    while (inputweight < 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter positive number of weight: ");
        inputweight = sc.nextInt(); 
    }

    // Check if the the total of weight is greater than the maximum before adding the weight of last passenger into the sum
    if (thesum+inputweight < inputmax)
        thesum += inputweight;
        count++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty trivial

You need to append one check to your code

```
 while(thesum < inputmax)
       {
           System.out.println("Enter each of weight: ");
           inputweight = sc.nextInt();

           while ( inputweight < 0)
            {
            System.out.println("Enter positive number of weight: ");
            inputweight = sc.nextInt(); 
            }
            thesum += inputweight;
            if((thesum >= inputmax)
            break;  // don't increase the count
            count++;   
        }
```

`